# Run an update program immediately after ClickOnce install

Tags: wpf, installation, clickonce

I've got a small WPF application which is being deployed to a client soon.  One of the prerequisites is Sql Express 2008, and the clickonce installer handles that part nicely.  My issue is that, after installation, I need to be able to unzip a backed up SQL DB, restore it, and set some user privileges.  I have the SQL and the code needed to do this, but I can't seem to figure out how to inject it into the clickonce install process, or how to force it to run some kind of "update" right after installation, before loading up the application.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: It might be better/easier to create a "normal" setup project instead of the ClickOnce, as those are highly customizable and more reliable (IMHO).

Comment: This was something I'd considered but was hoping to avoid... I am a big fan of the automatic sql express detection/installation by clickonce, and I don't have any experience with creating setup projects...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider checking IsFirstRun in your application and performing additional setup at that time. Using this method you can do just about anything you want.  Here's a snippet from [a webpage with more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.isfirstrun.aspx):

> Use IsFirstRun to determine whether
>   you need to perform any one-time
>   initialization operations the first
>   time your application runs.

Comment: This should work as long as the "set some user priveleges" doesn't involve elevated user access. ClickOnce apps will never run as an administrator.

Comment: +1 Good point. I overreached when I said "just about anything." Admin privs are not an option.

Comment: I went with this.  Since this is a preliminary release, we just told them that they needed to log in as an admin.  I suppose I'll ultimately need to create a traditional installer.  Thanks.

Comment: where in code can I use this code after the installation occurs? Main()?

Comment: @RichardBrightwell Can we go back to previous version if the database update fails?

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a [look at this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997001.aspx)? You could create a custom action.

I am not sure whether or not you will have/need elevated permissions but it might be worth a try,